# Is showing temporary result immediately better ux than showing a loading indicator until a result is available?

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, toggle, progress-bar

Use case: There is a toggle button a user can click on it. After the user clicked on it, it should show a result, success or failure. It takes some process time to calculate the result. Unless error happens, it should always give success result.

Which of the following is a better user experience after the user clicks the toggle button?

1. **Show success as a temporary result**, and if the process errors out later, revert the success result to failure. Should the toggle button be disabled while it is still processing the result? If it is not disabled, the user can keeps clicking the toggle button, what to do in that situation?
2. **Show a loading indicator**, and then show the result after the process gives the result. Should the toggle button be disabled while it is still processing the result and the loading indicator is present?

Comment: It really depends on what you're calculating and the value that information has to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show a loading indicator with a message such as "Processing", "Calculating", or a progress bar, if the wait time is longer than 2 or 3 seconds.

I can think of 2 reasons:

- Users might not understand or be really upset if they think they have succeeded, and eventually find out they failed.
- Some platforms actually lengthened artificially the processing time of requests, because users have been trained to associate waiting time and value, and they didn't trust results that appeared too quickly. Interesting discussion about this here: https://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/12/16/adding-delays-to-increase-perceived-value-does-it-work/
  If the delay is too long, it becomes a dark pattern, wasting user time.

Some ideas on how to make users enjoy their wait: https://www.sitepoint.com/make-users-enjoy-waiting/